# How do I exclude a table in loop that updates all tables pgsql

Tags: postgresql, loops, if-statement, sql-update, primary-key

I am trying to update all tables by setting the `id` field as the primary key. I have one table that does not have an `id` column, and need to skip it. This is what I have so far, but can't seem to get the query to run:

```
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE column_name = 'id'
                if not FOUND then
                     raise notice'no id found' 
                end if; END LOOP

    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)',
            rec.table_schema, rec.table_name, rec.column_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  missing "LOOP" at end of SQL expression
LINE 12:     end if; END LOOP;
```

Where is the `END LOOP` suppose to go, if not right after the if case? And is this event he right way to go about mass updating primary keys? Also, inside the if case, how do I make it so that the table is skipped rather than returning a notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. Missing DO before declare (typo perhaps)
2. You are missing the semi-colon (;) after the Select.
3. If statement unnecessary as the query has eliminated any table that
   would make it true.
4. End Loop following IF statement is invalid, at that point there is
   no loop.
5. Formatting the Execute Immediate will fail. It contains only 2
   arguments (%I) but you are passing 3 values. You need to add a 3rd
   argument for column or do not pass column name.

Taking all these into consideration:

```
do $$
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in 
        select table_schema, table_name 
          from information_schema.columns 
         where column_name = 'id'; 
    loop
        execute format('alter table %i.%i add primary key (id)',
            rec.table_schema, rec.table_name);
    end loop;
end;
$$;
```

There is still a big issue you need to address. What happens if the *table already has a primary key*, either id or any other column or even multiple columns.

To get only tables that do not have primary key change your select to:

```
select col.table_schema, col.table_name 
          from information_schema.columns  col 
         where col.column_name = 'id' 
           and not exists ( select null
                              from information_schema.table_constraints   con 
                             where col.table_schema    = con.table_schema 
                               and col.table_name      = con.table_name 
                               and con.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                          ) ;
```

This excludes any table having a Primary Key defined regardless of the columns it is defined on that would satisfy other requirements.

Comment: Thanks for all the corrections! I cleaned up the query and did end up running into tables that already have a primary key. Is there a way to exclude tables where they already have a primary key-- regardless of which column its set as?

Comment: Yes. See revised answer.